# one website will not show a java based editor on my laptop

Tags: internet-explorer-9, internet-explorer-10, java

This is a bit strange:
we upgraded our business website to Innova studio editor. when i attempt to use the editor the webpage comes up blank.  When i try the demo site for Innova the editor is usable.
i did the following: downgraded my browser from ie 10 to ie9 to ie8 and the problem still exists.

I uninstalled java and reinstalled and it still is blank

i deactivaed activex and the same

he editor works in chrome

any thoughts

I reinstalled ie9 and reset the browser... still no luck

Comment: The issue may easily be caused by the new editor...

Comment: the editor works on other websites and the editor works on other computers running ie10 and ie9